# mutating a dataframe using values from another dataframe as variable names in R

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach

I want to loop through the rows in a r dataframe (df1) and create columns based on the variable  values (v1) on each row.
V1 is a column name on the dataframe df1. What I want to do is add a column using the name V1 onto df2. Variable v1 is of the data type `<date>` and the values will all be dates.

This is what I tried

```
  for(row in 1:nrow(df1)){
    df2 %>%
      mutate(row$v1 == "value")
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this directly without a loop :

```
df2[as.character(df1$v1)] <- 'value'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer

```
for(row in 1:nrow(df1)){
  colname <- df1[row, "v1"]
  df2[,colname] <- "value"
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
Had to convert the colname into Character format since v1 was a date 

    for(row in 1:nrow(df1)){
      colname <- as.character(df1[row, "v1"])
      df2[,colname] <- "value"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
   mutate_at(vars(as.character(df1$v1)), 'value')
```